# Using VersionedTransactions with staking

Tags: web3.js, staking, versionedtransactions

I want to move to VersionedTransaction. But methods like StakeProgram.delegate, StakeProgram.deactivate return Transaction. How to use VersionedTransaction with staking?

Answer (score 2):

You can put in a PR with the implementations, but essentially you just need to change the inner function. For example, here's how you would do `delegate` with a versioned transaction:

```
  static delegate(params: DelegateStakeParams): Transaction {
    const {stakePubkey, authorizedPubkey, votePubkey} = params;

    const type = STAKE_INSTRUCTION_LAYOUTS.Delegate;
    const data = encodeData(type);
    const keys = [
        {pubkey: stakePubkey, isSigner: false, isWritable: true},
        {pubkey: votePubkey, isSigner: false, isWritable: false},
        {pubkey: SYSVAR_CLOCK_PUBKEY, isSigner: false, isWritable: false},
        {
          pubkey: SYSVAR_STAKE_HISTORY_PUBKEY,
          isSigner: false,
          isWritable: false,
        },
        {pubkey: STAKE_CONFIG_ID, isSigner: false, isWritable: false},
        {pubkey: authorizedPubkey, isSigner: true, isWritable: false},
      ];
          const message = new TransactionMessage({
        payerKey: signer1.publicKey,
        instructions: [
          new TransactionInstruction({
            data,
            keys,
            programId: this.programId,
          }),
        ],
        recentBlockhash: bs58.encode(recentBlockhash),
      });                                                                                     
      return new VersionedTransaction(message.compileToV0Message());
    });
  }
```

Note that I haven't tested this.